# custom attributes not saving in back end or importing unless certain option is set

Tags: attributes

I have programmatically created some custom product attributes as part of an import routine.  These have been assigned to an attribute set and they appear as expected in the admin alongside the appropriate products.  However, the values will not save either in the admin OR programmatically via a script.  That is, until I set "visible on product view page on front-end" to true.

Why should that make a difference?  Does setting that trigger some additional setting up of the attributes that I may have missed in the creation process? Once a value has been saved - I can switch off that option and it still works. Oddness.

Here is the function that is used to create the attributes

```
public function  newMagentoAttribute($name=null,$set=null,$sortOrder=null,$details=null,$productType="simple,grouped",$atttributeType="text"){
    /*with reference to code found here: http://pradeepkumarrcs.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/creating-new-attribute-and-adding-to.html [jh]*/
    $attr_data = array(
                'attribute_code' => $name,
                'is_global' =>1,
                'frontend_input' => $atttributeType, //'boolean',
                'default_value_text' => '',
                'default_value_yesno' => '0',
                'default_value_date' => '',
                'default_value_textarea' => '',
                'is_unique' => '0',
                'is_required' => '0',
                'apply_to' => array($productType), //array('grouped')
                'is_configurable' => '0',
                'is_searchable' => '1',
                'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => '0',
                'is_comparable' => '0',
                'is_used_for_price_rules' => '0',
                'is_wysiwyg_enabled' => '0',
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => '0',
                'is_visible_on_front' => '0',
                'used_in_product_listing' => '0',
                'used_for_sort_by' => '0',
                'frontend_label' => array($name)
            );
    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
    $model->addData($attr_data);
    $model->setEntityTypeId(Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('catalog_product')->getTypeId());
    $model->setIsUserDefined(1);
    if(is_numeric($sortOrder)){
        $model->setPosition($sortOrder);
    }
    try {
        $model->save();
        $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
        //-------------- add attribute to set
        $attribute_set_id=$setup->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', $set);
       // $attribute_group_id=$setup->getAttributeGroupId('catalog_product', $attribute_set_id, $group_name);
        $attribute_id=$setup->getAttributeId('catalog_product', $name);
        $groupId = $this->createGroupInSet($attribute_set_id,"AE");
        $setup->addAttributeToSet('catalog_product',$attribute_set_id,$groupId, $attribute_id);

        $this->existingAttrs[$name] = "";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->echoOut( 'ERROR: Sorry, error occured while trying to save the attribute. Error: '.$e->getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Ideally I  am looking for a "what might be going on is..." or "it doesn't work because..." type answer here - I want to understand the process.  Maybe it is the simple act of editing the attribute in the admin that triggers something to be set somewhere that makes it "complete"?

*** EDIT ***
Turns out I do not even have to change any of the attribute settings - I just need to load it then save it the admin.  Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share your codes here ?

Comment: oops for the extra t in atttributeType

Comment: Note: This is a dev environment - all the caches are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Try This code :-

```
private function createAttribute($code, $label, $attribute_type, $product_type)
{       
    $_attribute_data = array(
        'attribute_code' => 'old_site_attribute_'.(($product_type) ? $product_type : 'joint').'_'.$code,
        'is_global' => '1',
        'frontend_input' => $attribute_type, //'boolean',
        'default_value_text' => '',
        'default_value_yesno' => '0',
        'default_value_date' => '',
        'default_value_textarea' => '',
        'is_unique' => '0',
        'is_required' => '0',
        'apply_to' => array($product_type), //array('grouped')
        'is_configurable' => '0',
        'is_searchable' => '0',
        'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => '0',
        'is_comparable' => '0',
        'is_used_for_price_rules' => '0',
        'is_wysiwyg_enabled' => '0',
        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => '1',
        'is_visible_on_front' => '0',
        'used_in_product_listing' => '0',
        'used_for_sort_by' => '0',
        'frontend_label' => array('Old Site Attribute '.(($product_type) ? $product_type : 'joint').' '.$label)
    );


    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');

    if (!isset($_attribute_data['is_configurable'])) {
        $_attribute_data['is_configurable'] = 0;
    }
    if (!isset($_attribute_data['is_filterable'])) {
        $_attribute_data['is_filterable'] = 0;
    }
    if (!isset($_attribute_data['is_filterable_in_search'])) {
        $_attribute_data['is_filterable_in_search'] = 0;
    }

    if (is_null($model->getIsUserDefined()) || $model->getIsUserDefined() != 0) {
        $_attribute_data['backend_type'] = $model->getBackendTypeByInput($_attribute_data['frontend_input']);
    }

    $defaultValueField = $model->getDefaultValueByInput($_attribute_data['frontend_input']);
    if ($defaultValueField) {
        $_attribute_data['default_value'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam($defaultValueField);
    }


    $model->addData($_attribute_data);

    $model->setEntityTypeId(Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('catalog_product')->getTypeId());
    $model->setIsUserDefined(1);


    try {
        $model->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) { echo '<p>Sorry, error occured while trying to save the attribute. Error: '.$e->getMessage().'</p>'; }
}
```

See More here :-http://inchoo.net/magento/programatically-create-attribute-in-magento-useful-for-the-on-the-fly-import-system/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Arunendra.  The code is very similar to the one I am using.  Exceptions include adding in "is_filterable" and "is_filterable_in_search" values.  Should they really make the difference?

Comment: The attribute codes (field names) are calculated outside the function and need to be in certain formats.  That is one other difference in the code there.

Comment: I am looking for a "what might be going on" or "it doesn't work because" type answer here.

Comment: are you getting any error when trying to save it through admin ??

Comment: nope nothing, everything else saves fine - just ignores those custom attributes ...until I tweak a parameter in the attribute management - then they work

Comment: same when I try to update the product through a script.  The save object has them in but they just don't get saved.  Well they do now I have made the admin tweak but long-term that is a pain.

Comment: Have you check your log files, there might be some clue ??

Comment: Nothing in the logs or the report.  An exception is not thrown when saving.  It is just like those attributes do not exist or are not assigned to the product (even though they appear in the admin for the product and are in the db).  Odd isn't it.

Comment: It's strange behavior.Please also check logs are enable or not.

Comment: Oh they are - have log entries for other things

Comment: however, if one does a $myModel->setData("blueElephant",124);  This does not error generally anyhow.  *blueElephant" being a random non-existant attribute name